# Cannot play media Element programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I developed an app in Windows Phone 8. I have a list with mp3 from web and a mediaelement can't play them.

This is my code

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    play.Source = new Uri("http://n1.xtek.gr/ime_ploigos/rest/narrations/gr/10.mp3",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    play.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(note1_MediaOpened);
}

void note1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    play.Play();
}
```

And xaml is :

```
<MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="167,538,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Name="play" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

I have try it in xaml and play it but programmatically not. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to Play inside MediaOpened event. Just execute .Play after assigning Source to the MediaPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to button click event

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    play.Source = new Uri("http://n1.xtek.gr/ime_ploigos/rest/narrations/gr/10.mp3",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

   play.Play();
}
```